# I've run photorec to see if I could find some photos, I don't see any trace. Will running testdisk help?

Tags: testdisk, photo, photorec

I'm trying to find photos, they are in shotwell as "missing photos" so I thought I may have deleted them somewhere.  I ran photorec and after many hours, I can't see any trace of them.  Will running testdisk help?  what are the pros and cons...or the differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the new years hangover problem of copy pasting instructions from the net to reformat EUFI USB flash drive to FAT32 format. That involved filling the first 512 Megabytes of the drive with zeros. Unfortunately it contained "sdb" as the flash drive which happened to be my second drive on my system which was really 500 GB HDD.

Running `testdisk` (over 24 hours) I was able to repair the situation and get back my 250 GB Windows 7 drive (with all my Music and some work docs) and my 200 GB Ubuntu 14.04 partition with my historical code.

Rest assured `testdisk` is non-destructive unless you choose to have it update the disk, which I chose to do for copying backup `Boot Sector` over corrupted one and re-initializing `MFT` (whatever that is). Erring on the side of caution I ran `testdisk` over a 24 hour period and did lots of googling in between.

At the end of the day everything worked out fine and I can't say enough how happy I am with `testdisk`. Plus now I can write a good Q&A on how not to fry my hard disk using `dd` aka "Disk Destroyer" over the next week.

To summarize `testdisk` will not destroy your broken disk unless you choose to write out your changes. OTH it can save your data when you do write out changes on a broken disk.